# Group Policy Management Option Not Available

Tags: group-policy, windows-server-2016, wsus

I'm working on setting up WSUS and I'm following this guide [here](https://www.itprotoday.com/windows-8/deploying-windows-server-update-services-domain-environment-and-using-group-policies)

I got to the point of **Creating Group Policies and Linking on Client Computers OU to Point them on WSUS Server** but for some reason under tools on my dashboard I do not have the *Group Policy Management* choice, I've looked else where online and can't seem to find it.

My menu looks like this:

[image]

My menu is lacking options compared to other screenshots I've seen online. How do I find the Group Policy Management panel? Is there a menu setting I'm missing, or another way to open it? Any help is appreciated.

- note the tutorial I linked to is in regards to windows server 2012 and I'm currently running windows server 2016.

Comment: Is the Group Policy Management feature installed? If not, that's why it's absent.

Comment: Ah thanks didn't even think about that, kinda coming into a project that's already been started by someone else and not sure what has(nt) been done. Installing it now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How do I find the Group Policy Management panel? Is there a menu
>   setting I'm missing, or another way to open it? Any help is
>   appreciated.

You need to install the "Group Policy Management" feature on the server to configure policies, as shown in the screenshot below.

Please also note that after its installation, you should be logged in with a domain account for operating the Group Policy Management console successfully.

[image]